# set CompletionPolicy to commit entire file

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am creating a simple batch job that reads multiple files and posts the contents of each file as a separate message to a queue. Here is my code :-

```java
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("step1")
    public Step step1() {
        ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        try {
            String files = outputDirectory+"*.txt";
            resources = resolver.getResources("file:"+files);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error in the step1",e);
        }  
        customCompletionPolicy.setReader(readerPeek());
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
        .<String, String> chunk(customCompletionPolicy)
        .reader(multiResourceItemReader())             
        .writer(messageItemWriter)         
        .build();
    }


    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public MultiResourceItemReader<String> multiResourceItemReader() {
        MultiResourceItemReader<String> resourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<String>();
        resourceItemReader.setResources(resources);
        resourceItemReader.setDelegate(reader);
        return resourceItemReader;
    }


    @Bean
    @StepScope
    @Qualifier("reader")
    public FlatFileItemReader<String> reader() {    
        FlatFileItemReader<String> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setLineMapper(new PassThroughLineMapper());
        reader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new SimpleRecordSeparatorPolicy(){
            @Override
            public boolean isEndOfRecord(String line){
                return super.isEndOfRecord(line);
            }
        });
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("readerPeek")
    public SingleItemPeekableItemReader<String> readerPeek() {
        SingleItemPeekableItemReader<String> reader = new SingleItemPeekableItemReader<>();
        reader.setDelegate(reader());
        return reader;
    }
```

I am trying to create a CustomCompletionPolicy for this. Here is the class :-

```java
    @Component
public class CustomCompletionPolicy extends CompletionPolicySupport {

    private EOFCompletionContext cc;
    private PeekableItemReader<String> reader;

    public void setReader(PeekableItemReader<String> forseeingReader)
    {
        this.reader = forseeingReader;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isComplete(RepeatContext context)
    {
        return this.cc.isComplete();
    }

    @Override
    public RepeatContext start(RepeatContext context)
    {
        this.cc = new EOFCompletionContext(context);
        return cc;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(RepeatContext context)
    {
    }

    protected class EOFCompletionContext extends RepeatContextSupport
    {
        boolean endOfFile = false;
        public EOFCompletionContext (RepeatContext context)
        {
            super(context);
        }

            public boolean isComplete() {
            final String next ;
            try{
                System.out.println("Here I am in update");
                next = reader.peek();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new NonTransientResourceException("Unable to peek", e);
            }
            if (null == next){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the MessageItemWriter :-

```
@Component
```

public class MessageItemWriter extends JmsItemWriter{

```
private static final  Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageItemWriter.class);

@Autowired
@Qualifier("jmsTemplate")
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

@Autowired
private ConfigProps configProps;    


private int counter = 0;


@Override
public void write(final List<? extends String> items) throws Exception {
    logger.info("In the write "+items+"  "+items.size());
    //addDelay();
    simpleSend(items);
    logger.info("completed Posting");
}

public void simpleSend(final List<? extends String> items) {
    this.jmsTemplate.send(solaceJMSProps.getQueueName(), new MessageCreator() {
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            int mgsId = ++counter;
            TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage();
            String msgContent = items.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.joining(TransactionFileReaderConstants.COMMA));
            msg.setText(msgContent);
            msg.setIntProperty(TransactionFileReaderConstants.MESSAGE_ID, mgsId);
            msg.setJMSTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            logger.info("mgsId"+mgsId);
            msg.setJMSMessageID(String.valueOf(mgsId));
            logger.info("about to post: "+msg.getJMSMessageID());
            return msg;
        }
    });
}

private void addDelay() throws InterruptedException {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(configProps.getPauseTime());
}
```

}

The issue I am facing is that when i run this I get an error :

ERROR org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step processData in job midasFileReaderJob
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.SingleItemPeekableItemReader.update(SingleItemPeekableItemReader.java:145) ~[Transactions-Filereader-Batch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.SingleItemPeekableItemReader.updateDelegate(SingleItemPeekableItemReader.java:158) ~[Transactions-Filereader-Batch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]

Can someone please help me understand why this Error when i call peek() and what can I do to fix it ?

Thanks,
Himani

Comment: Can you share the code of your `messageItemWriter` please? If the goal is to send the content of the file verbatim as a message, I don't think a chunk-oriented step that reads each file line by line is the appropriate choice.

Comment: I just added the code for the MessageItemReader in the question above. I had tried using a MultiResourcePartitioner for this task and it was working fine for a small number of files. But as the number of files increased, it failed. I used 4500 small files on my dev bx and it failed. Prod is going to have several thousands of small files. So I switched to this approach.. but now even this seems to not work :(

Comment: ok thanks. Looking at your writer, you are re-collecting all lines in the message body. I see no need to read each file line by line and then re-assemble those lines in the message content. I added an answer with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are sending the file itself as a message, I see no need to read each file line by line then reassamble those lines in the writer. Hence, the `MultiResourceItemReader` approach is not appropriate.

I would define one item as one file and use a custom `ItemReader<File>` coupled with a `JmsItemWriter<File>`. This approach is:

- more efficient
- friendly to partitioning
- and solves the problem of trying to create a custom completion policy to commit the transaction for an entire file.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud!! thats exactly what i needed to do. So  created a CustomeFlatFileItemReader where in it reads the entire file instead of lines. I had been struggling with this for a long time... thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Mahmoud,I have a question - The scenario is that i am getting a large file with millions of records. some records are similar based on the first N bytes and must be sent in the same msg. so I chunked the file into smaller files-  where records with same N bytes are in the same file. This created thousands of small files. When I tried using a MultiResourcePartitioner with a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor, It crashed after reading about 2000 files.  I got an OOM error.  Im using a MultiResourceItemReader with a CustomFlatFileItemReader. but its slow. Can you pls suggest some way to make more efficient.

Comment: As I said, MultiResourceItemReader is not appropriate. Use a single threaded chunk-oriented step that reads files from a directory. If you have a lot of files, you can partition them in different directories and use a partitioned step where each partition is a directory.

Comment: Can you please point me to s  sample document or a example that i can refer to? I dont think I understand it very well.

Comment: nevermind , I got it.. I was able to implement it. I will post my code here so it might help someone facing a similar problem. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I drill down to the `MultiResourceItemReader` 's source codes (version 4.2.1) and I don't think it can be achieved easily without some hack of the current codes. It is mainly because when the `MultiResourceItemReader` switch to read from the next Resource , it does not expose this switching event to the outside world such that other object cannot detect this event and act accordingly. All states about detecting this event are private too which means even implementing a custom reader by extending `MultiResourceItemReader`, we still cannot access these information.

Because of this , using `PeekableItemReader` to implement a custom `CompletionPolicy` also does not work mainly because from the `PeekableItemReader` 's point of view , it still does not know when this switching event happens. It only know if there are still items available to peek from the underlying `MultiResourceItemReader` by treating all resources as a single resource , it does not know whether there are available item to peek from the current and individual resource.

I suggest you to ask for this feature at the spring-batch official github.

Alternatively , you can change to use `MultiResourcePartitioner` to create a partitioned step per file as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44880452/spring-batch-multiresourceitemreader-chunk-commit-per-resource).

Comment: I tried using the partitioner but It fails due to the size of data. I am actually getting a large file with 50 million records. I then break the file into smaller files containing similar records.  Then we need to send each of these small files as a seperate message.  I created about 4500 files and tried using the partitioner with a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor (with concurrency of 10) and it crashed after reading and posting 2000 files. In production the number of files will be a several thousands... Im not sure if the MultiResourcePartitioner will be able to handle the load

Comment: Ken,  I tried using just the FlatFileItemReader bean instead of MultiResourceItemReader in the job, along with my completionpolicy but I still get the error. java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.SingleItemPeekableItemReader.updateDelegate(SingleItemPeekableItemReader.java:157)      I think Im not wiring them correctly.  Can you please share any examples of how to wire such a completionPolicy with the job